# Reading the file in java

Tags: java, file

I don't understand this: I have "Text.txt" in the same directory as my java files but my code keep throwing a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Text.txt (No such file or directory)`. Could somebody please tell me if I did anything wrong? I'm only concerned why my code is throwing an exception. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
public class PrintLongestLines {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("Text.txt"));
        int numberOfLines = file.nextInt();
        String biggestLine = "";
        String[] myArray;
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;

        while(file.hasNextLine()){
            if(!file.hasNextInt()){
                count++;
            }   
        }

        myArray = new String[count];
        while(file.hasNextLine()){
            if(!file.hasNextInt()){
                String line = file.nextLine();
                myArray[index++] = line;
            }   
        }
        String[] resultArray = new String[numberOfLines];
        for(int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++){
            if(myArray[i].length() > myArray[i-1].length()){
                biggestLine = myArray[i];
            }
            else{
                biggestLine = myArray[i-1];
            }
        }
        resultArray[0] = biggestLine;
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            if(myArray[i].length() > myArray[i-1].length() && !myArray[i].equals(resultArray[0])
                                                            && !myArray[i-1].equals(resultArray[0])){
                biggestLine = myArray[i];
            }
            else if(myArray[i].length() < myArray[i-1].length() && !myArray[i].equals(resultArray[0])
                    && !myArray[i-1].equals(resultArray[0])){
                biggestLine = myArray[i-1];
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you running this code in netbeans or eclipse or .. ?

Comment: @vlatkozelka, eclipse

Comment: You say "in the same directory as your 'java files' - where is that? How are you running this? there are many reasons why this might not work, we need more information. Also, post the stacktrace.

Comment: *"I have "Text.txt" in the same directory as my java"*, well, it is wrong there. It should be in the project root directory.

Comment: Where is Text.txt, Absolute path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791986/getting-filenotfoundexception-even-though-file-exists-and-is-spelled-correctly

Comment: `/home/username/workspace/Practice/src`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197187/filenotfoundexception-even-when-the-file-is-there

Comment: Please do a print of `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` and make sure you are *really* on the folder you *think* you are...

Comment: There are many questions on StackOverflow regarding the same issue.Please consider googling before postong a question here.Possible duplicate for many...

Answer (score 2):

The path (at run-time) isn't the source folder. You can check the runtime path with something like,

```
try {
    System.out.println(new File("Text.txt").getCanonicalPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And you might instead read relative to a user's home folder. Something like,

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");  
System.out.println(new File(home, "Text.txt").getCanonicalPath());
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477222/reading-the-file-in-java#comment56696140_34477222).

Your text file is inside `/home/username/workspace/Practice/src` which is source folder of your project and `new File("Text.txt")`  will look into  root folder of your project which is `/home/username/workspace/Practice`. You can move your file to `Practice`.

Or you can find file in following way inside the source folder, with the help of class loader.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(PrintLongestLines.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("Text.txt"));
```